# What does . mean in a JS function when it's used as in .data = [...]

Tags: javascript

Example is from d3js.org.

```
d3.selectAll("p")
   .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
   .style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });
```

Please elaborate on the syntax being used .data and .style. Why is it written this way? What does it refer to?

Comment: It's a chainable method which is defined on an object, so called using `.` operator.

Comment: Gotcha --- I didn't reaize d3.selectAll("p").data(.... was the same as what is written above. Thanks